# Different results for sum ifs

Tags: arrays, excel, sumifs

Any thoughts why I am getting different values for these formulas?

```
=(SUMIFS(SF[ratenight],SF[OmniTier],"=Within1",SF[bedrooms],"=1")+SUMIFS(SF[ratenight],SF[OmniTier],"=Within2",SF[bedrooms],"=1"))
```

=363

```
=SUMIFS(SF[ratenight],SF[bedrooms],"=1",SF[OmniTier],{"Within1";"Within2"})
```

=146

Comment: Try wrapping the second formula in a `SUMPRODUCT`.  My guess is that it's returning the sum of "Within1" because it doesn't know to sum both results of "Within1" and "Within2" together since `SUMIFS` is designed to return a single sum, so it's just returning the first one.  `SUMPRODUCT` will see that there are two sums and provide the correct result.  So: `SUMPRODUCT(SUMIFS(SF[ratenight],SF[bedrooms],"=1",SF[OmniTier],{"Within1";"Within2"}))`

Comment: thanks @tigeravatar!

Comment: On a related note: can we get around to using `, 1, ` in place of `, "=1", `? A [SUMIFS function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIFS-function-C9E748F5-7EA7-455D-9406-611CEBCE642B) will read a `1` and a `"1"` the same.

Comment: @jeeped thanks for helping me clean further. The answer is yes!